# Summing across in a dataframe with condition coming from another column

Tags: r, dplyr

this is not a very good title for the question. I want to sum across certain columns in a data frame for each group, excluding one column for each of my groups. A simple example would be as follows:

```
df <- tibble(group_name = c("A", "B","C"), mean_A = c(1,2,3), mean_B = c(2,3,4), mean_C=c(3,4,5))
df %>% group_by(group_name) %>% mutate(m1 = sum(across(contains("mean"))))
```

This creates column m1, which is the sum across mean_a, mean_b, mean_c for each group. What I want to do is exclude mean_a for group a, mean_b for b and mean_c for c. The following does not work though (not surprisingly).

```
df %>% group_by(group_name) %>% mutate(m1 = sum(across(c(contains("mean") & !contains(group_name)))))
```

Do you have an idea how I could do this? My original data contains many more groups, so would be hard to do by hand.

Edit: I have tried the following way which solves it in a rudimentary fashion, but something (?grepl maybe) seems to not work great here and I get the wrong result.

```
df %>% pivot_longer(!group_name) %>% mutate(value2 = case_when(grepl(group_name, name) ~ 0, TRUE ~ value)) %>% group_by(group_name) %>% summarise(m1 = sum(value2))
```

Edit2: Found out what's wrong with the above, and below works, but still a lot of warnings so I recommend people to follow TarJae's response below

```
df %>% pivot_longer(!group_name) %>% group_by(group_name) %>% mutate(value2 = case_when(grepl(group_name, name) ~ 0, TRUE ~ value)) %>% group_by(group_name) %>% summarise(m1 = sum(value2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option where you can just use `group_name` directly with the tidyselect helpers:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(m1 = rowSums(select(across(starts_with("mean")), -ends_with(group_name)))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
  group_name mean_A mean_B mean_C    m1
  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A               1      2      3     5
2 B               2      3      4     6
3 C               3      4      5     7
```

**How it works**

1. The row-wise output of `across` is a 1-row tibble containing only the variables that start with `"mean"`.
2. `select` unselects the subset of the variables from output by `across` that end with the value from `group_name`.
3. At this point you are left with a 1 x 2 tibble, which is then summed using `rowSums`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way how we could do it:

1. We create a helper column to match column names
2. We set value of mean column to zeor if column names matches helper name.
3. Then we use `transmute` with `select` to calculate `rowSums`
4. Finally we `cbind` column `m1` to `df`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(helper = paste0("mean_", group_name)) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("mean"), ~ifelse(cur_column()==helper, 0, .))) %>%
  transmute(m1 = select(., contains("mean")) %>% 
           rowSums()) %>% 
  cbind(df)
```

```
  m1 group_name mean_a mean_b mean_c
1  5          a      1      2      3
2  6          b      2      3      4
3  7          c      3      4      5
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about cur_column() function, that's great.